# Media Foundation with C#

Tags: c#, .net, video, ms-media-foundation

**Media foundation** is the recommended technology by Microsoft and it has really  supported it by a lot of samples and explanation but all are with the native code

I found a wrapper in **sourceforge** make me able to use Media Foundation with C# but while I am reading people talk about not every thing can be done by the managed code

I have some tasks to do with MF:

1. Capture alive video
2. change resolution and baud rate
3. Encode video
4. decode video

Can I use .net in these tasks or I have to use the native code?Is there samples help (please don't mention msdn one from them)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Media Foundation is great to work with, and performs very well.  If your requirements include real-time, you will be best served by writing your own C++/CLI wrapper to orchestrate the overall process.  I assume you mean bit rate (as opposed to baud rate).  Are you wanting to capture a webcam stream?  Are you encoding /decoding to possibly more than one media type? Is audio included?

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your answer yes I want to capture a webcam stream and while I am capturing it I encode frames each time cycle and append it to the desk,I can put in one container not many(may be byte stream also without container).I need video only I am not caring about audio at all

Comment: I'm no media foundation expert but I have found the best way to interact between it an C# is to use Managed C++. I've managed to capture live video from Media Foundation to my C# WPF application. The main C++ class is here but be warned again that I'm no expert on MF http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#sipsorcery-media/SIPSorcery.Media/MFVideoSampler.cpp.

Answer (score 4):

The Media Foundation .NET C# wrapper can work well for all those tasks you mentioned. I've used it personally to implement the capture, resizing, and encoding, and I imagine decoding shouldn't be too hard either.

The project does have some examples you can download but I find them rather lacking.  The wrapper is so close to the C++ implementation that it's not too hard to use C++ examples and just port the logic to C#.  I used the following as a reference and found it to be very valuable:
https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples

Comment: Where do you find the Media Foundation .NET C# wrapper? Is there an official release or are you referring to the "snarfle" project at source forge?